# Can one use on-premises Kubernetes to manage clusters deployed in a hybrid cloud?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, hybrid-cloud

If one is running Docker Enterprise with Kubernetes in an on-premises private cloud, is it possible to add clusters in a public cloud like Azure?

Comment: What is your definition of `manage` ?

Comment: GCP has solutions to orchestrate other Kubernetes clusters hosted on-prem or in AWS.

Comment: Thank you @NeoAnderson.  I will check that out.

Comment: The question is quite broad. Can you be more specific about the goal? Do you plan to have a parallel cluster running in a public cloud with a centralized control point or just add more nodes to your on-prem Kubernetes cluster, hosted on a public cloud vendor? I can provide some references for GCP, as for solutions on Azure, maybe other folks do have more expertise than me.

Comment: @NeoAnderson Yes and yes. I.e., we don't know yet.  Whether it's a single cluster distributed across multiple clouds (is that even possible) or multiple/parallel clusters in separate clouds, a centralized control point is desired.  We want the scalability of public cloud, with the option of multi-vendor and hybrid architecture.  So far I'm hearing of Kubefed, Azure arc, Istio, Banzai Cloud Pipeline.  Also open to vendor specific solutions that support multi-cloud clusters. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Whether it's a single cluster distributed across multiple clouds (is that even possible) or multiple/parallel clusters in separate clouds, a centralized control point is desired. We want the scalability of public cloud, with the option of multi-vendor and hybrid architecture. So far I'm hearing of Kubefed, Azure arc, Istio, Banzai Cloud Pipeline. Also open to vendor specific solutions that support multi-cloud clusters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On GCP, Anthos is a candidate.
You may have a look on their [architecture](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/concepts/overview) and see if it fits your needs.
Anthos is advertised in most of the GCP architecture courses and offers integration between GKE and both on-prem(the on-prem cluster must meet some prerequisites or you can use the version provided by Google) and AWS Kubernetes clusters.

Istio is a service mesh and if I understood correctly your requirements, [the multiple clusters](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/deployment-models/#multiple-clusters) and [multiple networks](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/deployment-models/#multiple-networks) models could be used.

Answer (score 2):

why don't use rancher for that , you can manage on-premise and GKE AKS EKS  or cluster installed in ec2.

it's a great tool for that

Comment: Thanks @breish5729.  If you have the knowledge to compare Rancher to other mature products (not beta or preview-only products like Azure Arc or KubeFed) that are vendor-neutral, I would consider this the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is where Azure Arc can help you to achieve this requirement. However it is in preview stage as of now, i hope soon it will be generally available.

From the [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/overview),

> You can attach and configure Kubernetes clusters inside or outside of
> Azure by using Azure Arc-enabled Kubernetes Preview. When a Kubernetes
> cluster is attached to Azure Arc, it will appear in the Azure portal.
> It will have an Azure Resource Manager ID and a managed identity.
> Clusters are attached to standard Azure subscriptions, are located in
> a resource group, and can receive tags just like any other Azure
> resource.

Answer (score 1):

[cluster API](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api) under kubernetes SIG is an open source project which provides declarative APIs and tooling to simplify provisioning, upgrading, and operating multiple Kubernetes clusters.

Cluster API can be extended to support any infrastructure provider (AWS, Azure, vSphere, etc.) or bootstrap provider (kubeadm is default) you need. There is a growing list of [supported providers](https://cluster-api.sigs.k8s.io/reference/providers.html) available.

You can use cluster API and build your own custom management plane based on cluster API if vendor provided software is not an option for you.

If you are looking for a vendor provided management plane which can be hosted on prem and can manager life cycle of a on prem kubernetes cluster as well as a cluster on any public cloud provider such as AWS, GCP, Azure then [Tanzu Mission Control](https://tanzu.vmware.com/mission-control) from VMware  is an option. Internally it uses cluster API.

Personally I would not use Anthos or Arc because they seem to be a way to get locked into a specific vendor

Comment: thank you.  I appreciate your desire to be vendor neutral.  The Cluster API is only a prototype at this point, or I would mark this as the answer.

Comment: Yes it's in prototype but VMware is already using it in their vsphere product..sometimes you need to take a leap of faith and bet on an early stage technology